# How to load XML from external API into local object

Tags: c#, xml

I'm attempting to load the XML from an external web service into objects using the URL: http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/services/mnis/members/query/fymp=ST1

From what I can find online in regards to this I've already made the objects and added the XMLRoot and XMLElement attributes as such:

```
public class Member
    {
        [XmlElement("DisplayAs")]
        string DisplayAs { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("ListAs")]
        string ListAs { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("FullTitle")]
        string FullTitle { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("LayingMinisterName")]
        string LayingMinisterName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DateOfBirth")]
        string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("DateOfDeath")]
        string DateOfDeath { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Gender")]
        string Gender { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Party")]
        string Party { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("House")]
        string House { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("MemberFrom")]
        string MemberFrom { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("HouseStartDate")]
        string HouseStartDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("HouseEndDate")]
        string HouseEndDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("CurrentStatus")]
        CurrentStatus CurrentStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class CurrentStatus
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Reason")]
        string Reason { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("StartDate")]
        string StartDate { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Members")]
    public class Members
    {
        [XmlElement("Member")]
        List<Member> MemberList { get; set; }
    }
```

And I can read the XML from the URL with an XML Text Reader:

```
public void GetMemberByPostcode(string postcode)
        {
            string Url = "http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/services/mnis/members/query/fymp=" + postcode;
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Url);

        }
```

But I don't seem to be able to find anything online that will allow me to get from here to having my objects populated with the XML data. Can anyone advise on the best way to do this or point me in the direct of a tutorial or post that will show me how its done?

Comment: you have to use an `HttpClient` of some sort.

Comment: You just read the xml and deserialize it into your object... here is [one online example.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1163664/Convert-XML-to-Csharp-Object)

Comment: You will need to use an XML serializer to transform the data into your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that your model should have public properties with setter and getter the XML deserializer to work.
After that changes use this code:

```
string Url = "http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/services/mnis/members/query/fymp=ST1";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Url);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Members));
var members = (Members)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: This could be me being stupid - but I though they already had public getters and setters? `string DisplayAs { get; set; }` - aren't these public by default and isn't the `{ get; set; }` shorthand for getters and setters?

Comment: Of course not. The class members private by default (i.e. if omit access modifier.)

Comment: So changing them to pubic should fix that right? The `{get; set;}` will be ok as they are?

Comment: Yes. Changing them to public should fix that.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WebClient.DownloadString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the XML as a string.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string xml= client.DownloadString(address);
```

Then deserialize the XML string to an instance of your class.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Members));
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
  var members= (Members)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```